# Output arrays to CSV

Tags: arrays, csv, powershell

I have two CSVs:

1. `Total 19_01_16.csv`:

   ```
   hostname,user,path,size,creation,LastAccess,Copied,NewName,Completed
   comp1,user1,\\comp1\users1\file.pst,100,17/02/2015,17/01/2016,Yes,file_user1_.pst,
   comp1,user1,\\comp1\users1\file2.pst,200,17/02/2015,17/01/2016,Yes,file2_user1_.pst,
   comp2,user2,\\comp2\users2\file.pst,100,17/02/2015,17/01/2016,Yes,file_user2_.pst,
   ```
2. `PST Passwords.csv`:

   ```
   user,Path,Password1,Password2,Password3,Error
   user1,\\comp1\users1\file.pst,openme,openme,openme,
   ```

I'm trying to merge the two with different headers and additional content. 
This is what I have so far:

```
$a = Import-Csv "$PST_PARENT\DailyReports\Total 19_01_16.csv"
"Hostname,User,PST_Name,Original_Path,New_Path,Size,AcceptableLoss,Password1,Password2,Password3" |
  Set-Content "$PST_PARENT\DailyReports\New Build.csv"

$a | foreach {
  $HOSTNAME  = $_.hostname
  $USER      = $_.User 
  $PATH      = $_.path
  $NEW_NAME  = $_.NewName
  $NEWPATH   = "$PST_SHARE\$USER\$NEW_NAME"
  $SIZE      = $_.Size
  $SIZE_FAIL = ( [convert]::ToSingle( $SIZE ) / 2 )

  $b = Import-Csv "$PST_PARENT\DailyReports\PST Passwords.csv"

  $b | foreach {
    if ( $USER -like $b.user ) {
      $PASSWORD1 = $b.password1 
      $PASSWORD2 = $b.password2
      $PASSWORD3 = $b.password3
    } else {
      $PASSWORD1 = "none"
      $PASSWORD2 = "none"
      $PASSWORD3 = "none"
    }
  }

  $HOSTNAME,$USER,$NEW_NAME,$PATH,$NEWPATH,$SIZE,$SIZE_FAIL,$PASSWORD1,$PASSWORD2,$PASSWORD3 | 
    Add-Content "$PST_PARENT\DailyReports\New Build.csv"
}
```

The output of `New Build.csv` looks like this:

```
Hostname,User,PST_Name,Original_Path,New_Path,Size,AcceptableLoss,Password1,Password2,Password3
comp1
user1
file.pst
\\comp1\users1\file.pst
\\share\PST_Storage\file_user1_.pst
100
5
none
none
none
```

In essence the output is working, it's just not scrolling for each line, it's putting each array onto a new line.
I tried adding `| ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation` but all that did was convert the arrays to numbers, they still went down not across.

Any ideas? Am I on the right line or doing the whole thing so very wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$HOSTNAME,$USER,...` defines an array, which is written to the output file one element per line. You need to put the list in double quotes to turn it into a comma-separated string that you can write to the output file as a single line.

```
"Hostname,User,PST_Name,Original_Path,New_Path,Size,AcceptableLoss,Password1,Password2,Password3" |
  Set-Content "$PST_PARENT\DailyReports\New Build.csv"

$a | foreach { 
  ...
  "$HOSTNAME,$USER,$NEW_NAME,$PATH,$NEWPATH,$SIZE,$SIZE_FAIL,$PASSWORD1,$PASSWORD2,$PASSWORD3"
} | Add-Content "$PST_PARENT\DailyReports\New Build.csv"
```

or you construct a custom object from the elements that you can export via `Export-Csv`.

```
$a | foreach { 
  ...
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'Hostname'  = $HOSTNAME
    'User'      = $USER
    'NewName'   = $NEW_NAME
    'Path'      = $PATH
    'NewPath'   = $NEWPATH
    'Size'      = $SIZE
    'SizeFail'  = $SIZE_FAIL
    'Password1' = $PASSWORD1
    'Password2' = $PASSWORD2
    'Password3' = $PASSWORD3
  }
} | Export-Csv "$PST_PARENT\DailyReports\New Build.csv" -NoType
```

Comment: Thanks. Angry at myself for not spotting something so simple, so obvious. 

The fresh eyes have done the job. Very grateful. Thanks again